# How to plot an equation with two variables in 2D

Tags: plotting

I am unable to plot 2x^2 + y = 3 where {x,0,1} and {y,0,1} in 2D **I am able to get it in 3D and DensityPlot** Hope someone could guide me

Comment: Add your code please, also the working code with `Plot3D` and `DensityPlot`.

Comment: Plot3D[2x^2 + y ==3,{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]

Comment: f = 2x^2 + y - 3  and  DensityPlot[f,{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]

Comment: What does the result from `Reduce[2 x^2 + y == 3 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}]` tell you? Or the output from `ContourPlot[2 x^2 + y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ContourLabels -> All]`?

Comment: `Plot[y /. Solve[2 x^2 + y == 3, y][[1]], {x, 0, 1.15}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1.15}, {0, 1.15}}]`

Answer (score 1):

Look at:

```
    Reduce[2 x^2 + y == 3 && 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1, {x, y}]
(* x == 1 && y == 1 *)
```

So in the prescribed square, the *only* point on the graph of the equation $2 x^2 + y = 3$ is $(1,1)$.

The usual way to plot an implicit equation such as that is by using `ContourPlot`. But since the contour will degenerate to a point, just enlarge the domain:

```
    ContourPlot[2 x^2 + y, {x, 0, 1.15}, {y, 0, 1.15}, Contours -> {3}, 
        ContourShading -> None, Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{1, 1}]}]
```

[image: Contour of x^2 + y = 3]